# Не удается получить доступ к объекту C#

Tags: c#

```
 public class XhtListener : NetWorker
    {
        private HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
        public XhtListener(IReadOnlyCollection<string> prefixes)
        {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
            {
                   ///
            }
            if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Count == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");
            foreach (var s in prefixes)
            {
                _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
            }
        }
        public override void Start()
           {
                if (!WorkFlag)
                {
                    WorkFlag = true;
                }

                var tr = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (WorkFlag)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            _listener.Start();///вот на этом строке
                            if (!_listener.IsListening) continue;
                            HttpListenerContext context;
                            context = _listener.GetContext();
                          `//////` }
```

Есть вот такой код но при работе на этом строке `_listener.Start();` получаю
вот такую ошибку `Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.HttpListener'.`

Comment: Капитан Очевидность сообщает: пока вы собирались вызвать ему Start() - ему кто-то успел вызвать Dispose().

Comment: если я ни где больше не использую это кто ещё может вызывать ??

Comment: Вы сами и вызываете. Чудес не бывает.

Comment: И как интересно?????

Comment: @PavelMayorov с кривоватым кодом чудеса бывают :). Даже во фреймворке.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это сообщение вводит в заблуждение, к сожалению. `HttpListener` выбрасывает исключение `ObjectDisposedException` в случае, если вы пыетесь вызвать какой-то метод у экземпляра, который находится в закрытом состоянии. А перейти в закрытое состояние `HttpListener` может в трех случаях:

1. Кто-то вызвал `Dispose()`/`Close()`.
2. Во время вызова `Start()` произошла ошибка.
3. Кто-то вызвал `Abort()`.

Так что проверяйте свой код на предмет вызова `Dispose()`/`Close()`/`Abort()`, а также исключений при вызове `Start()`.

Немного подозрительно выглядит код, который вы привели. Что там у вас в `catch`? Не происходит ли у вас при первом вызове `Start()` ошибки и не пытаетесь ли вы в цикле вызывать `Start()` у одного и того же объекта?

```
while (WorkFlag)
{
    try
    {
        _listener.Start();///вот на этом строке
        if (!_listener.IsListening) continue;
        HttpListenerContext context;
        context = _listener.GetContext();
```

Comment: судя по приведенному коду _listener только один раз инициализируется, поэтому второй вариант выглядит самым правдоподобным

Comment: @Grundy ну поскольку полного кода автор не привел, остается только гадать. Может у него там и другие вызовы где-то притаились :).